# Dynamic templates with Django and Ajax

Tags: django, templates, django-templates, javascript-framework

My question is a bit generic in that my problem is a broad one. I have been working with django for some time, and I really want to move more into doing very dynamic web pages where actual page reloads aren't common.

I have read about the different popular javascript frameworks available, and I always feel like I am missing part of the puzzle, particularly in templating.

What are some of the best practices for keeping my templating code as non redundant as possible. I get the impression that a lot of templating logic will make it's way into the JS in addition to my django templates. I want to avoid situations where I am writing templating code in two different places.

For a very basic example, let's say I am writing some template code inside Django for an input field that has a set number of attributes. I have then also written in JS that when I click on a button, another input field of the same type is generated with all the appropriate attributes. In practice this could be a form that takes an arbitrary amount of e-mail addresses. The problem I see is that when I want to change something about that input field, I need to do it in two places.

Is there a particular development paradigm or work flow that I am unaware of? How are issues like this generally avoided?

Recommendations on frameworks would be amazing too!

Answer (score 1):

as you mentioned above:

Use Django Template language. Pass the data from view to template dynamically.

Read [Django Template Language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/) documentation.

**For JS** :
    its better to write your js in home.html.... use {% include %} tag for other    html

Comment: I don't think this entirely answers my question. My biggest issue is figuring out a good way to keep UI elements generated on page load by the templating system, and ones I create dynamically with javascript to be consistent without modifying two places in my code base. Is there an elegant solution or paradigm for this?